# Design wrong of navigation drawer in tabbed Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a problem with my navigationdrawer of my tabbedActivity.

I have a problem of design if I can say like that.
When I open the navigation drawer, I'd like that he opens like this (this is another activity of my app) :

[image: Good_design]

But instead it opens like this in my tabbed activity :

[image]

How can I move down my navigation drawer so it doesn't cut the title of my activity ?

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
fitToSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/menu_navigation"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: give fitToSystemWindows="true"  for DrawerLayout in xml

Comment: it still doesn't work, can you check my updated question with the code please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your toolbar to outside of the drawerLayout. 
Since now the toolbar is having drawerLayout as its parent, that's why its showing like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    fitToSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/menu_navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And how should I do that ? Can you correct my xml file please ? Because I can't move oustide of the drawerLayout as I made it..

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/some_margin"
    android:id="@+id/menu_navigation"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
```

**add margin top to your `NavigationView`**

Comment: this actually changed something but my menu opened at the middle

Comment: I just added a top margin to whatever you have posted. You have to implement it properly, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Make this change to your navigation view.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:id="@+id/menu_navigation"
app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu">
```